# Charge at rest:with respect to what?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, inertial-frames

Electrostatics is study of charges at rest and electrodynamics the study of charges in motion. But we know that rest and motion is relative. We cannot say that something is at rest or in motion without defining the frame of reference. So in which frame we  consider charges to be at rest or in motion??

This must also implies that for different frames we would observe charges to behave differently. Like if in a frame moving with constant speed w.r.t. ground will see a charge (at rest w.r.t. ground) moving. So in this frame a scientist will not say that it's electrostatics but it's electrodynamics so there must be some magnetic field produced . But on the ground we will say that there is no magnetic field produced.

Who is correct ? Is both of them correct ? Or none of them correct??

Comment: Any frame. If there is _a_ frame where all charges are just at rest, you can use electrostatics in that frame.

Comment: The frame of reference will chosen wrt to the substance on which the charge is present .

Comment: The "at rest" defines the frame, it means that initially all particles have momentum zero.

Comment: Both are correct. And SR accounts for this change with the electromagnetic tensor. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism

Comment: But knzhou if I use electrostatics in a frame and another observer in another frame says it's not electrostatics then won't both of us be using different things for the same thing .               And our frame of reference should not change the actual physics?

Answer (score 2):

Electric field and magnetic field are not basically independent.they are the two aspect of the same entity that is electromagnetic field.the electromagnetic field will show up as an electric field or a magnetic field or a combination depends on the frame from which you are looking at the field.

Look there is nothing so called" who is correct" . Ex - you are moving on earth , earth will say you are going forward , you will say earth is going backwards ,

Tell me who is correct ? 
 So please don't mess up with relativity , hunting over the absolute .